# List UIBB Schema - add Column - how?

Tags: abap, webdynpro

I want to add a Column on the existing UIBB Schema i have
(SOLMAN_WORKCENTER - > TEST SUITE ANALYTICS - > Defect Analysis)

I tried to Enhance the Component Configuration.

[image: List UIBB Schema]

So I thought i could simply add additional Columns of choice by entering the (+)Column wizard.

[image: add Column wizard]

But the Column I need is not pre-included.

What is the correct way of adding extra columns to a UIBB Schema?

Comment: What means "not preincluded"?

Comment: not possible to select